# PHP MVC should submit news has the same view file as edit news?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Users can submit news and edit them afterwards. My question, should they have the same view file with a few ifs `if(page == edit) echo "edit news" else echo "submit news"` and similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think sharing the same **form** for add/edit is the way to go, and much more DRY (Don't repeat yourself). In Ruby on Rails, it's a a really good practice/standard to do that.

So yeah, create two views for add and edit, but include the same form in both of your views, so you would have something like:

```
create.php
edit.php
_form.php
```

and you would simply include the _form.php in each of the file.

I would still create two views because most of the time you have different texts, images and other things surrounding the form, so if you don't want to have *ifs* everywhere, I would create two views to keep things organized and clean :)

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what RoR fanatics would tell you: Views are full blown instances of different classes and not just stupid templates. A proper View is responsible for presentation logic and juggles multiple templates.

In this case, you are basically doing same thing. You would be using same view with same templates. Even at [datamapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) (do not confuse with ORMs of same name.. no relationship) level the application would be using executing the same [`UPSERT`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsert) statement with all the same fields. Only in one case `newsId` would be `NULL`, and in other - some number, representing primary key in table.